# Django how to get selection of forms.Form

Tags: python, django, forms, return-value

How I can process a selection (RadioButton selection) further in my **views.py** ?

Currently I'm processing this staticaly for btc (Bitcoin) but I have to get this working for ltc, xmr etc. as currency also.
How can I get the user selection of this form or in other words the selected currency the user has chosen?

my **views.py**:

```
...
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CurrencyBuySelectForm(request.POST)
    currency = form['currency'].value()
    # check account balance
    if form.is_valid:
        if currency == 'btc':
            price = dollar_to_coin(item.price_usd, 'BTC')
            if request.user.acc_btc_balance < price:
                messages.error(request,'Not enough balance to buy this item')
                return redirect('item', pk=item.pk)
            else:
                # do blabla
                ...
```

my **forms.py**:

```
WALLET_CHOICE = [
    ('btc', 'BTC'),
    ('xmr', 'XMR'),
    ('ltc', 'LTC'),
    ... 
]

class CurrencyBuySelectForm(forms.Form):
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WALLET_CHOICE, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CurrencyBuySelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['currency'].label = mark_safe('')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CurrencyBuySelectForm, self).clean()
        currency = cleaned_data.get(choices=WALLET_CHOICE, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
        if not currency:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Something went wrong')
```

handling this like described here does not seem to work:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you must :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   form = CurrencyBuySelectForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid()
   request.GET.get['currency']
```

with request.GET.get['currency'] you can grasp what user selected and posted.

Comment: get() takes no keyword arguments,

i do: currency = form['currency'].value()
            # check account balance
            if form.is_valid():
                request.GET.get['currency']
                if currency == 'btc':...

Comment: As soon as i packed the choices into a dict i got the following error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to add a dict

```
my_dict= {'btc': 'BTC', 'xmr': 'XMR', 'ltc': 'LTC'}
```

and then reference them via `my_dict.keys()` and `my_dict.values()`.

Something like:

```
if currency in my_dict.keys:
    val = my_dict[currency]

price = dollar_to_coin(item.price_usd, val)
```

EDIT:
Regarding the assignment of `currency` in **views.py**, it may be best to add another method to your `CurrencyBuySelectForm` class. The `clean()` method should only clean the data, you could then add a `currency()` method that carries out the assignment and checking of `currency` and returns it. This then allows you to reference it using `currency = form.currency()`

Something like:

**views.py**

```
my_dict= {'btc': 'BTC', 'xmr': 'XMR', 'ltc': 'LTC'}

if request.method == "POST":
    form = CurrencyBuySelectForm(request.POST)
    currency = form.currency()
    # check account balance
    if form.is_valid:
        if currency in my_dict.keys():
            price = dollar_to_coin(item.price_usd, my_dict[currency])
            if request.user.acc_btc_balance < price:
                messages.error(request,'Not enough balance to buy this item')
                return redirect('item', pk=item.pk)
            else:
                # do blabla
```

**forms.py**

```
WALLET_CHOICE = [
    ('btc', 'BTC'),
    ('xmr', 'XMR'),
    ('ltc', 'LTC'),
    ... 
]

class CurrencyBuySelectForm(forms.Form):
    currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WALLET_CHOICE, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CurrencyBuySelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['currency'].label = mark_safe('')

    def clean(self):
        self.cleaned_data = super(CurrencyBuySelectForm, self).clean()

    def currency(self):
        self.currency = self.cleaned_data.get(choices=WALLET_CHOICE, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
        if not self.currency:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Something went wrong')
        return self.currency
```

Comment: thanks so far, but what do i do with: currency = form['currency'].value() ??

Comment: This solution seems not to be wrong at all but somehow i now get: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
Which only appears if a use a dict at my forms.py

Comment: I've edited my answer to try and address your issue, let me know if this works :)

Comment: Nope, this returns KeyError currency

Comment: cleaned_data and if not currency seems not to be reachable at def currency

Comment: Editted my answer again, forgot to make cleaned data and currency instance variables, we'll get there eventually!

Comment: still Exception Type: KeyError at /buy
Exception Value: 'currency'

Comment: beside that, the following line(s):

"price = dollar_to_coin(item.price_usd, item[currency])" indicated at "[" that the mentioned model class the item object belongs to does not define "__getitem__" so the operator [] cannot be used for this instance... Any idea how to resolve this?